# Specified Cast is Invalid Getting MAPIOBJECT from MailItem.AddressEntry using Late Binding

Tags: c#, outlook, mapi, late-binding

I'm trying to get the MAPIOBJECT of the MailItem.AddressEntry using Late Binding with Outlook.

I keep getting "Exception has been thrown by target of invocation" and an inner exception of "Specified Cast is Invalid" and I have no idea why. Nothing has come up on Google searches etc.

Firstly I know that the MAPIOBJECT is deprecated and not visible through intellisense but works.

I can get the object no problems without late binding.

Here is the code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the MAPI Object from the AddressEntry of the new recipient.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="senderName">The name of the sender to add to the recipients.</param>
/// <param name="outlookApplication">The Outlook Application instance.</param>
private static object GetMapiObject(string senderName, object outlookApplication)
{
    var mailItem = InvokeMember("CreateItem", outlookApplication, new object[] { 0 });
    var recipients = GetProperty("Recipients", mailItem);
    var recipient = InvokeMember("Add", recipients, new object[] { senderName });

    InvokeMember("Resolve", recipient, new object[] {});
    var addressEntry = GetProperty("AddressEntry", recipient);

    var mapiObject = GetProperty("MAPIOBJECT", addressEntry); // Error occurs here.
    return mapiObject;
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets a property of an instance by its name
/// </summary>
/// <param name="propertyName">The property name to get.</param>
/// <param name="instance">The object to get the property from.</param>
/// <returns>The resulting object.</returns>
private static object GetProperty(string propertyName, object instance)
{
    Type type = instance.GetType();
    return type.InvokeMember(propertyName, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, instance, new object[] { });
}

/// <summary>
/// Invoke an object by its method and type - takes parameters.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="method">The method to invoke.</param>
/// <param name="instance">The object that contains the method to invoke.</param>
/// <param name="parameters">The parameters to pass to the method.</param>
/// <returns>The resulting object.</returns>
private static object InvokeMember(string method, object instance, object[] parameters)
{
    try
    {
        Type type = instance.GetType();
        return type.InvokeMember(method, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance, parameters);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        switch (method)
        {
           case "SaveAsFile":
                throw new System.IO.IOException("Error occurred during \"SaveAsFile\" for attachments. Attachment filename may be too long. ", ex);                                                

            default:
                throw new TargetInvocationException("Handled error at Invoke Member. Method Name: " + method, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have to use the MAPI interface as you are, I would strongly recommend using the [MAPIEx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CMapiEx.aspx) project in CodeProject.

This made our MAPI integration go very, very smoothly.

And, worst case, the source code could shed light on specific questions, such as this.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using that! It's very helpful and allowed me to do what i was after.

Comment: There is a [brand new, high-quality **article on managed MAPI**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/455823/Managed-MAPI-Part-1-Logon-MAPI-Session-and-Retriev) over there on the Code Project.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, MAPIOBJECT is not deprecated, just invisible.
Secondly, where does your code run? If it is an exe other than outlook.exe (i.e. your code is not in a COM add-in), you must call MAPIInitialize().

Comment: MSDN says it's depreciated. My code runs outside of outlook. I tried adding that before this line: var mapiObject = GetProperty("MAPIOBJECT", addressEntry); but to no avail. is this the right call: MAPIInitialize(IntPtr.Zero);

Comment: Yes, that should work. What happens? Why do you need IMailUser MAPI object?

Comment: Alos, are you sure you call MAPIInitialize exported from the right dll?

Comment: I need that to get the SMTP Address from the sender using the HrGetProp method